# How to Send an embedded Javascrippt Object using formData and axios

Tags: javascript, axios, form-data

Hi i am trying to send some data to a nodejs server using formdata and axios
Below is the data:

```
let hostel =[
 {
  hostel: "Joslian",
  coordiantes: [1.5465465,-1.546546],
  room: {
    name: "Single",
    price: 5201
  }
 },
 {
  hostel: "Joslian",
  coordiantes: [1.5465465,-1.546546]
 }
]

form = new FormData();
form.append('hostel', hostel)
```

How can i send such king of data to the sever using formdata.

Answer (score 0):

Try make post request with `FormData`, you can get example [here](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/318)

```
const body = new FormData();
body.append('foo', 'bar'); 

axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'url',
    data: body,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
})
```

Comment: @Mav Vem Thanks for your answer but the problem is not with axios actually when i send the data i am able to get the data but in an invalid way. My probel is how to next that object into the form data because for single values works fine but for an objects it does not work

Comment: Oh okay, try this `form.append('hostel[]', hostel)`, sorry i can not check it out right now, maybe it help you